# Notification on client desktop without involving server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am building web application to keep track of activities of users using an Angular front-end and the back-end using `PHP`. User click start button, what activity he/she is doing. When user click the start button, timer start to run. But sometimes user may forget to stop timer or just close the browser. What i want to is to notify to the user desktop with some notification something like web push notification when activity goes too long. And my question is

1.Is it possible to notify the user when he/she close my web in browser,but     his/her desktop is on? and how?

2.How to send push notification to the user desktop without interacting with server?

I see some tutorial like push notification where server send notification but I have nothing update in database I have my clock running in AngularJS. So I have to check clock time also in Angular. As Angular is a framework of JavaScript, I am comfortable with JavaScript too. Any ideas how to use `GCM` or ServiceWorker or push notification. I am new to `GCM`, push notification and service worker.

Any suggestions?